# Lubuntu 20.04: Full-screening a window resizes it to 1080p instead of 1200p

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, 20.04, window

I recently did a fresh install of Lubuntu 20.04. Full screening on my 1600x900 laptop screen is as expected. On my Dell 24", 1200p monitor, full screening leaves a strip visible at the bottom where other windows or the background wallpaper can be seen.

It took me a few moments but this appears to be the size difference and position where a 1080p monitor would have ended.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue so that full screening on the 1200p extended monitor will cover the entire display area?

[image: fullscreen attempt]

**Update to questions**

1. On the (sole) extended monitor, I have a 1900x1200 resolution. It is the native resolution of the monitor
2. Graphics card: Intel HD 4000 integrated GPU
3. I click the middle mini-icon between _ and X on the top right corner.
4. All windows on the extended monitor are affected. All windows on my laptop display are not affected. I just tested and confirmed the same window on the extended display causes the “visible background strip” to appear on the extended display, but not on the laptop monitor. I believe there is an incompatibility with 1900x1200 resolutions.
5. After running `openbox --restart` the problem persists. Restarting the computer also does not fix the issue. I’ll also note Lubuntu 20.04 is my only installed OS.

Comment: Interesting bug. Please tell us more, and maybe we can help. It would be best if somebody with the same resolution will see your question and be able to help. So: 1. What is the screen resolution (also the horizontal number of pixels)? 2. What is the graphics card (brand name and model)? 3. How do you set full screen (F11)? 4. Will it affect all graphical programs or only some of them?

Comment: Try `openbox --restart`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1484292

Comment: I tested switching between different resolutions in Lubuntu 20.04 LTS [persistent] live, and I was **not** affected by this bug. But I have no mode with 1200 pixels vertically, and I have probably other graphics hardware ...